# How to change background color with bb code

Tags: php, css

I am trying to make bbcode system. I want to replace
`[bg=color code]color text[/bg]`
to
`<span style="background-color:color code;">color text</span>`

by `preg_replace`.Any idea for me?

Comment: Will this help? http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bbcode.php

Comment: No. I can't understand that. Please give me the php script.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
<?php
function showBBcodes($text) {

    $find = array(
        '~\[background-color=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/background-color\]~s'
    );

    $replace = array(
        '<span style="background-color:$1;">$2</span>'
    );

    return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}

$bbtext = "[background-color=green] This is Backgroud color text [/background-color]";
$htmltext = showBBcodes($bbtext);
echo $htmltext;
?>
```

Comment: This is tested code. and working fine if you need any assistance then please  let me know.

Comment: Hi Hapless, if it really help you then you need to accept the answer :)